# R-Dplyr Moving Sum Over Unevenly Spaced Data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset with over one million rows.  Each record in the data has a customer-key, a product-code and a timestamp.  The problem is to determine, for each record, the number of times the same product code was used with the same customer key in the past seven days.

A brute-force algorithm for doing this is straightforward:

```
Sort data by customer-key, then by product-code, then by time-stamp (descending).
Outer loop through the sorted data
{
    Set counter = 1
    Inner loop through sorted data, starting from the outer-loop record + 1
    {
        If outer-loop customer key matches inner-loop customer key 
           AND outer-loop product-code matches innter-loop product-code
           AND outer-loop timestamp - inner-loop timestamp < 7 days
                counter += 1
        Else
                Break inner loop
    }
    Append counter-value to outer-loop record
}
Resort data into original timestamp order.
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this using dplyr with R, without explicit loops?

(Note: There are too many rows and the timestamps are too uneven, i.e. sometimes there are seconds between records, other times weeks; to allow putting the data into an evenly-spaced grid to be an option).

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output. thanks

Comment: Looks like a good use case for `slider::slide_index()`, which allows calculations of one variable over time windows specified by another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by joining the table with itself. Most likely something like the following:

```r
output = df %>%
  left_join(df, by = c(customer_key, product_code), suffix = c("", "_joined")) %>%
  mutate(close_purchase = ifelse(abs(timestamp - timestamp_joined) < 7, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(customer_key, product_code, timestamp) %>%
  summarise(counter = sum(close_purchase))
```

Comment: I will try this out, and accept if it works.  The self-join may be the piece that wasn't coming to me, that replaces the explicit loop.  Thanx!